# Are there any provers based on a paraconsistent logic?

Tags: software-request, paraconsistent

[This question](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/277/have-any-proof-assistants-incorporated-a-notion-of-unsafety-with-type-type) talks about controlled usage of a self-containing top type satisfying $\text{type}\! : \text{type}$.

I'm wondering if there are any provers that deliberately give $\text{type}\!: \text{type}$ a designated truth value, but *still make it paradoxical*.

(Note: I'm using the term *prover* generically to refer to a proof assistant or automated theorem prover.)

---

This would require weakening the propositional (fragment of the) logic used by the prover in question.

There are some [paraconsistent logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraconsistent_logic) out there where $A \land \lnot A$ is not a contradiction, or, equivalently, $A$ and $\lnot A$ are not mutually exclusive.

For example, the [Logic of Paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-paraconsistent/#ManyValuLogi) is paraconsistent as is [the relevant logic R](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-relevance/logicr.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure this is the answer you are looking for, but here it is anyways.

In the proof-as-program paradigm embraced by dependent type theory, inconsistency is not necessarily an issue. Indeed, one does not only care about the *truth value* of a given statement, as you seem to imply, but also about the computational content of proofs of that statement. For instance, the `bool` type is inhabited but nobody will ever conflate it with the `unit` type, which is also inhabited.

All mainstream functional programming languages are inconsistent when seen as logical systems, because using ML syntax it is possible to write a proof `boom : unit -> 'a` as a non-terminating loop `let rec boom () = boom ()`. When seen through the Curry-Howard mirror, `boom ()` is actually a proof of an arbitrary theorem. Yet nobody complains that such languages allow writing non-terminating programs.

By contrast, most dependent type theories prevent this kind of situation by restricting side-effects in general, and non-termination in particular. It is nonetheless possible to design impure dependent type theories, resulting in an inconsistent logical system but a perfectly fine dependently-typed programming language. A simple example of such an object is the [Exceptional Type Theory (ExTT)](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01840643/document) which can be given as a program translation from MLTT to itself. Because of this you can systematically write ExTT programs in pretty much any proof assistant based on MLTT, through a simple transpilation phase.

ExTT allows raising exceptions, and thus inhabit any type. Still, the equational theory is not degenerate and you get a decent language. Moreover, the target theory also allows to reason safely about those programs and ensure that in some cases, the exception-raising terms are actually well-behaved and do not raise toplevel exceptions. In the end, paraconsistency is in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is a satisfactory example, however Yatsuka Nakamura's THEAX system is inconsistent. There was no intentionality on Nakamura's part; indeed, he discusses the problem in the [technical report](https://web.archive.org/web/20010725135949if_/http://markun.cs.shinshu-u.ac.jp/kiso/projects/mathematics/Theax-e/Math-e-mj.htm).
Then he solved it by joining Mizar; in fact, Nakamura is one of the historical contributors to Mizar's library and the second most prolific after Yasunari Shidama.