# Correcting formally verified results

Tags: mathematics, verification, bugs

John Harrison spoke once about checking the results of some peer reviewed mathematical research: he has found bugs in the proofs and even a faulty theorem, which he corrected by giving a formal proof.

Are there examples of doing this for already formalised theorems? Definitions might be wrong, logics might be expressing something bad.

Comment: Relevant https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/1219/has-anyone-ever-accidentally-proven-a-false-theorem-with-type-in-type/1232