# What is the type-in-type problem in idris2 and can it be avoided?

Tags: idris

If I understand it, this [video series](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCgH_Hwn4U5xL97ghUGFzPyA) mentioned that idris2 currently has some type-in-type problems, so that one can exploit it to prove false claims. I am not familiar with the concept, and am concerned whether I should learn idris2 as a proof assistant/language. The speaker said then that it will probably be fixed sometime in the future, but it is not clear whether that has happened (as of 0.6.0).

So my questions are:

*What's a good example of the type-in-type problem that leads to a falsely proved claim?*

*If one uses idris2 as a proof language, is there a way to use it carefully (in a disciplined way) to avoid the "type-in-type" problem?*

Answer (score 2):

See the following references:

- A. J. Hurkens, ["A simplification of Girard's paradox"](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0014058), Proceedings of the 2nd international conference Typed Lambda-Calculi and Applications (TLCA'95), 1995.
- [`Coq.Logic.Hurkens`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.Hurkens.html) for a formal derivation of the paradox.

In principle you cannot know for sure whether type-in-type creeped in somehow and caused a problem, and it has been known to happen, as discussed in [Has anyone ever accidentally "proven" a false theorem with type-in-type?](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/1219/has-anyone-ever-accidentally-proven-a-false-theorem-with-type-in-type). However, I would say you should just go ahead and use Idris. So long as you're doing "normal" things, it should be ok. Also, it's exciting to live dangerously.

Comment: For concreteness, an example usage of the Hurkens package in Coq is: `From Coq Require Import Hurkens. Unset Universe Checking. Definition Hurkens'_paradox := PropNeqType.paradox eq_refl : False.`